# Legend and Color For HeatMapLayer using Point Count - Azure Maps

Tags: azure-maps

I would like to add a legend to my Heat Map Layer using LegendControl Module. I want to add StopColors in the legend using the number of points. However the HeatMapLayer color option only allows HeatMapDensity (0 to 1) in the data expression. How do we assign colors to HeatMapLayer using "interpolate" expression and the number of points ?

```
 color: [
    'interpolate',
    ['linear'],
    ['heatmap-density'],
    0,
    'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    0.2,
    'royalblue',
    0.4,
    'cyan',
    0.6,
    'lime',
    0.8,
    'yellow',
    1,
    'red'
  ],
```

However adding ['get','point_count'] to the color throws error inplace of heatmap_density. How to create a legend and color the heat map based on number of points ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are trying to create a weighted heat map. Use the `weight` option. For example:

```
var layer = new atlas.layer.HeatMapLayer(datasource, null, {
   weight: ['get', 'point_count']
});
```